# How do I debug this in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

This comes up from time to time. Acumatica will throw an error (popping up an error box). It is usually on the "MoveNext" command, but it sometimes happens in other events. But when I attach VS2022 to the IIS app, it never throws an error inside of my debugger, so I can't see where the problem is.

This is the latest example of this...

First this is the C# Extension code:

```
public class OpportunityMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    internal CurrentCostingInfo currentCostingInfo = null;
    public static bool IsActive()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelecting<CROpportunity> e, PXRowSelecting InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
            if (e.Row == null) return;
            var row = e.Row as CROpportunity;
            if (UseMarkupInsteadOfMargin == null || !UseMarkupInsteadOfMargin.HasValue)
                UseMarkupInsteadOfMargin = false;

            SetDisplayFor_MarkUpOrMargin("CROpportunity", UseMarkupInsteadOfMargin, e.Cache);

            using (new PXConnectionScope())
            {
                SetOpportunityMarginTotals(row);
            }
        int h = 0;
    }


    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldSelecting<CROpportunity, CROpportunity.status> e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;
    }

    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<CROpportunity, CROpportunity.status> e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;
    }


    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<CROpportunity> e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        int i = 0;
        InvokeBaseHandler?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
        int f = 0;
    }
```

When I Run it, this is what happens:

1. IsActive() gets hit, of course.
2. Then I hit the (Events.FieldSelecting<CROpportunity, CROpportunity.status> e) 5 times.
3. Then I hit the Events.RowSelecting method.
4. When I leave RowSelecting, I don't hit any more breakpoints, but this error message shows in Acumatica:

[image: Invalid Cast]

RowSelected() is never hit, and neither is the FieldDefaulting method.

This is the Trace info for Exceptions:

> System.InvalidCastException2023-06-05 17:58:45 UTC Specified cast is
> not valid.
>
> PX.Data.PXException2023-06-05 17:58:45 UTC Error: An error occurred
> during processing of the field Account ID:
>
> Specified cast is not valid.. PX.Data.PXException2023-06-05 17:58:45
> UTC Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Account
> ID:
>
> Specified cast is not valid.. PX.Data.PXException2023-06-05 17:58:45
> UTC Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Account
> ID:

Trace for Error:    System.InvalidCastException

```
at PX.Data.PXFirstChanceExceptionLogger.ProfilerFirstChanceException(Object o, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs args)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at PX.Data.PXDataRecord.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at PX.Data.PXDBIdentityAttribute.RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.CreateItem(PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at PX.Data.PXView.CreateResult(PXCache[] caches, PXDataRecord rec, Boolean hascount, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)
   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)
   at PX.Data.Automation.Services.NavigationService.FindExistingRow(PXView view, Object current, Object[] searches, String[] sortColumns)
   at PX.Data.Automation.Services.NavigationService.GetExistingRow(PXView view, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters)
   at PX.Data.Automation.Services.NavigationService.NavigateToScreen(INavigationScreenInfo screen, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 evaluatedParameters, WindowMode windowMode, String navigationMessage)
   at PX.Data.PXGenericInqGrph.NavigateTo(String urlOrScreenID, WindowMode windowMode, Nullable`1 lineNbr)
   at PX.Data.PXGenericInqGrph.<>c__DisplayClass88_3.<GenerateResultField>b__9(PXAdapter adapter)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.RunHandler(PXAdapter adapter)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__38.MoveNext()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.DataBind()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.CollectDataControls(Dictionary`2 controlsDic, List`1 controlsList)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.RenderClientData(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod, XmlWriter writer)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.GetCallbackResultInternal(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.GetCallbackResult(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RenderCallback()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
PX.Data.PXException2023-06-06 13:43:29 UTC
```

Trace for: PX.Data.PXException:

```
at PX.Data.PXFirstChanceExceptionLogger.ProfilerFirstChanceException(Object o, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs args)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.CreateItem(PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at PX.Data.PXView.CreateResult(PXCache[] caches, PXDataRecord rec, Boolean hascount, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)
   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)
   at PX.Data.Automation.Services.NavigationService.FindExistingRow(PXView view, Object current, Object[] searches, String[] sortColumns)
   at PX.Data.Automation.Services.NavigationService.GetExistingRow(PXView view, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters)
   at PX.Data.Automation.Services.NavigationService.NavigateToScreen(INavigationScreenInfo screen, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 evaluatedParameters, WindowMode windowMode, String navigationMessage)
   at PX.Data.PXGenericInqGrph.NavigateTo(String urlOrScreenID, WindowMode windowMode, Nullable`1 lineNbr)
   at PX.Data.PXGenericInqGrph.<>c__DisplayClass88_3.<GenerateResultField>b__9(PXAdapter adapter)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.RunHandler(PXAdapter adapter)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__38.MoveNext()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.DataBind()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.CollectDataControls(Dictionary`2 controlsDic, List`1 controlsList)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.RenderClientData(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod, XmlWriter writer)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.GetCallbackResultInternal(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXCallbackManager.GetCallbackResult(PXCallbackResultMethod resultMethod)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RenderCallback()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at PX.Web.UI.PXPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

So the issue is with "AccountID" -- except there is no AccountID field in the database table that I can see.

How do I go about seeing what is really going on? I need it to allow the system to throw an error, but it seems to be suppressing that and handling it in the popup, which tells me next to nothing.

Comment: If you unpublish your customisation, you don't get the error ?

Comment: Correct. If I unpublish I do not get the error. It has to be a problem with my customization somewhere.

Comment: Then I don't think the error is in this extension. Have you checked the trace for clues ?

Comment: Nothing in it makes sense to me. But, I am no expert in reading the trace log. I'll add the detail from it, and you can see if anything jumps out at you.